# How to prevent the text in `single-value` div from overflowing into the `indicators` div in React-Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-select

## Summary

- In my form using a [React-Select](https://react-select.com/home) component (I'm using v2.4.1), the label inside the `single-value` div can overflow into the `indicators` div, as shown:
  [image: overflowing label]
  Here is how the component is called:

```html
<Select
  name="Country1"
  className="Countries"
  classNamePrefix="React_select"
  options={this.state.Options}
  value={this.state.Country1}
  onChange={(option) => this.handleSelect("Country1", option)}
  aria-label="Select a Country"
/>
```

## Background / already tried

- I have tried setting the following css properties on the `single-value` div:

```css
.React_select__single-value {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

- I also tried these on other divs, like the `value-container` and `container`.

## Expected vs. actual results

- Those settings do not seem to make any difference.
- *However,* adding `max-width: 200px;` produces the desired effect:
  [image: correctly truncated label].
- While this will work for now, is there a way that will scale better or is more correct?

Comment: can you add padding to the right of single values to make up for the space indicators takes up?  Do you have a better demo?  It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the markup.

Comment: I've added the markup to show how the component is called, and your suggestion to add some `padding-right` to `single-value` works well, thanks!

Comment: Could you produce a live version on codesandbox.io or somewhere else ? I try to reproduce your issue and I don't have it